# The behavior of China as a future superpower

Tags: china, power

Considering the rising British Empire during the early 18th century and the current superpower, the USA, during the mid-19th century, and the USSR during the early 20th century, is China behaving any differently as a potential future superpower?

I.e., is there any noticeable difference between 21st-century china, 20th-century USSR, 19th-century USA, and 18th-century Britain in terms of imperialism and hegemonistic ambition?

Comment: It would be more productive to ask about similarities rather than differences, as there are far fewer of them (between all of the mentioned powers).

Comment: 17c Britain was so utterly different from early 20th c USSR that this question is like asking if there is any noticeable difference between apples and orangutans.

Comment: @JamesK, I am not comparing apples and orangutans; I am comparing if orangutans crave apples in the same way as chimps. If so, how? if not, why not?

Comment: @JamesK Maybe OP meant 18th century? Because Britain in 17th century was mostly concerned with its own internal problems. Britain weren't even properly united until 1707.

Comment: 19th-century USA??? The US was at most a regional power in the 19th century. By the time of the 1898 Spanish-American war, Spain had declined in power so as to be nowhere close to being a superpower, and the US was at most a wannabe regional power. The US only came to superpower status with WWII.

Comment: Britain set out to protect its trade routes and ended up with a (pretty successful) empire by mistake. Then when the sell-by date was passed it shook off its empire and downsized almost painlessly (compared to other empires). That is probably unique in history.

Comment: FUTURE superpower ??

Comment: I would say by late 19th Century, the U.S. was definitely a regional power.  It became the fist nation after the UK to field a post-dreadnaught battleship, and the first ship of this line was under construction concurrently with the HMS Dreadnaught.   At the time, U.S./U.K. relations were not as strong, largely because the U.S. foreign policy was generally to only get involved in European Politics if they got involved with politics in the Americas, and largely worked to keep Europe out of the New World.

Comment: This question might be more historical than political. Another stackexchange might be better suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. China has not gone to war recently (for the past several decades) except for some minor border skirmishes with India, while the US, UK and USSR all fought many wars in the periods you are interested in.

- [US wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_the_United_States#19th-century_wars)
- [Soviet wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Russia#Soviet_Union_(1922%E2%80%931991))
- [British wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_the_United_Kingdom#United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_and_Ireland_(1801%E2%80%931922))

And compare vs.

- [Chinese wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_wars_and_battles#Sino-Vietnamese_conflicts_(1979%E2%80%931991))

Comment: The only reason China hasn't invaded any country outright is because it is focused on developing its economy and fears economic sanctions. However, as it has become more confident with it economic growth and international diplomacy, it has certainly started using its military more aggressively in low-intensity conflicts to resolve territorial disputes.

Comment: The USSR hasn't fought any wars in the last few decades, either.

Comment: @Obie2.0 the question asks about "21st-century china, 20th-century USSR, 19th-century USA, and 18th-century Britain", and you'll notice the links point to those specific epochs.

Comment: The "only" reason?

Comment: @Obie2.0 Err...what? The USSR hasn't been around for the last few decades, but in that time Russia has been involved in [14 wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Russia#Russian_Federation_(1991%E2%80%93present)), several of which were very much Russian invasions of independent states The USSR in its last three decades was involved in ten wars, again some of which were actual invasions of independent states. ¶ Possibly you meant that as some sort of joke or sarcasm, but I can't see what it would refer to.

Comment: I am pretty sure the recent conflict China has with India at the border is manufactured by both governments to divert the attention of its citizens from their respective domestic mismanagments

Comment: @cjs - I stand by what I said. The USSR has not fought any wars in the last few decades.

Comment: @Obie2.0 That contributes nothing but noise to the discussion.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a pretty lazy *political* prognostic:  "I know,  I'll post links to spreadsheets of battles without context".

Comment: @Obie2.0 [Sure about that?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/71689).

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica - Neo-Soviets are not the USSR.

Answer (score 11):

**No**, there isn't much difference in the "imperialistic" ambitions and behaviour of China vs the old superpowers.

Imperialism did not begin with outright invasion and occupation of a future colony. It often began with trade, which the imperialists used as an opportunity to establish themselves there. They would then use their economic and military might to force trade concessions in their favour. (And ofcourse, during the imperialistic era, even outright militarily conquer the weaker nation states or kingdoms).

China seems to be following the same path.

Africa is a good example that is highlighted often in this context. In its search for raw materials for its industry, China has been increasingly making deep investments in Africa. They also convince some of the governments to allow them to bring Chinese workers to the Chinese companies in Africa. And they setup chinese communities in those country.

> It happened in Zambia like it could happen elsewhere in Africa. Chinese investors made deals with the government to mine its natural resources, filling federal coffers with billions of dollars. Chinese immigrants moved into cities and rural towns. They started construction companies; opened copper, coal, and gem mines; and built hotels and restaurants, all providing new jobs. They set up schools and hospitals. But then instances of corruption, labor abuse, and criminal coverups began to set the relationship between the Chinese and the Africans aflame.

> ... “***China takes our primary goods and sells us manufactured ones. This was also the essence of colonialism***,” Lamido Sanusi, the governor of the Central Bank of Nigeria, wrote in the Financial Times earlier this year.

Source: [China in Africa: The New Imperialists?](https://www.newyorker.com/news/news-desk/china-in-africa-the-new-imperialists)

The hallmark of European colonialism was the imbalanced trade in which raw materials was harvested from the colony and then have manufactured goods sold back to them by the imperialist country. China, as the manufacturing hub of our current world, seems to following the same pattern.

And, just like in the past, China also seems to be competing with other "imperialist" powers.

Sudan is a very good example, where the Chinese have invested heavily by building pipelines and oil refineries and they now import around 2/3 of the oil output of Sudan. They have even deployed Chinese soldiers to protect Chinese workers and their infrastructure in Sudan. All this has annoyed the USA, as US oil companies previously had the upper hand in exploiting the Sudanese oil fields. The US has tried to bring oil embargo sanctions against Sudan (citing the political conflict in the country) but China has always threatened to veto it in the UN.

> “***It is surprising, the coincidence that U.S. sanctions began around the same time China invested in our oil industry,***” a Sudanese government official offers sarcastically. China has invested in other aspects of the industry until it controls as much as 75 percent of the Sudanese oil industry. Sudan currently produces 133,000 barrels of oil per day — a fraction of what it produced before the south of the country seceded in 2011, taking most of the country’s proven oil reserves with it.

Source: [Sudan: China’s Original Foothold in Africa](https://thediplomat.com/2017/06/sudan-chinas-original-foothold-in-africa/)

Another way it tries to economically subjugate another country is by creating "debt-traps" for them. The term was coined by the US and the gist of it is that China targets countries that is strategically important to them (economically and militarily), that have weaker and poorly managed economy and encourages them to take huge loans from China to build some infrastructure, some of which are not even commercially viable. The debt, and any commercial failure of the project and / or the country's economy, is then used by the Chinese as leverage to make more demands on the country.

Pakistan and Sri Lanka are very good examples of this kind of "debt traps", where their failing economy and the huge loans from China has made them very vulnerable to China.

> Two countries in the neighbourhood, Pakistan and Sri Lanka, signed up for massive Chinese debt-funded infrastructure projects, slipped into economic crisis, and now are caught in political turmoil. In a third country, Myanmar, the Chinese have moved back in after the military coup 14 months ago, and are pushing projects for an economic corridor. In the Maldives too, Chinese-funded projects and loans have risen and fallen with changes of government. Estimates of the Maldives debt to China vary sharply — the opacity is typical because China has a history of hiding loans as trade credit or by routing them through special purpose vehicles. And Chinese debt isn’t cheap; interest rates seem to be about three times what other countries charge on bilateral aid.

> ... What is China’s role and responsibility? Like a sharp moneylender, it stepped in where it saw opportunity and picked targets carefully. **Projects and loans went to resource-rich or strategically-placed countries, 70 per cent of which did not have a good credit rating or any rating at all**, and which therefore had few, if any, alternative sources of external finance. **It protected its interests by holding project assets as collateral**, taking over quite a few. **Lending has therefore been followed by asset-grab** ... China exacerbated but did not mostly cause the problem, whose roots lay in the borrowing countries’ broken politics and economic mismanagement.

Source: [China’s ‘debt-trap diplomacy’ played role in Pakistan, Sri Lanka crises. But it’s not the cause.](https://theprint.in/opinion/chinas-debt-trap-diplomacy-played-role-in-pakistan-sri-lanka-crises-but-its-not-the-cause/908740/)

> ... in South Asia, with the Indian Ocean and Indo-Pacific as new theatres of contestation, Beijing will, and has capitalised on opportunities to further entrench its presence, influence, and leverage in the region. Sri Lanka is a prime example of China having taken advantage of internal fiscal mismanagement and debt. A [New York Times investigation](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/25/world/asia/china-sri-lanka-port.html) into the 99-year Hambantota Port deal and 15,000 acres of surrounding land that was given to a state-owned Chinese company revealed an insistence on the Chinese side to focus on handing over equity in the port, rather than allowing any easing of negotiating terms with the Sri Lankans. Additionally, **while China explains the deal as a purely commercial endeavour, Sri Lankan officials have stated the intelligence and strategic opportunities the port offers were part of the negotiations** – aspects that have serious security implications for India.

> ... **China has also included dubious clauses in bilateral agreements** that directly contradict the benign nature of the BRI and reinforce the proactive debt trap diplomacy in other parts of the world. Montenegro is one such case where China has loaned €800 million to build a highway. A provision under the agreement states if Montenegro were to default on repayment, China would get the right to access Montenegrin land as collateral – directly alluding to a strategy of seizing assets in case of inability to repay. This will provide China a direct entry into Europe.

> China’s ‘debt trap diplomacy’ is not a figment of imagination. While it may have decided, for strategic reasons, to keep it in abeyance in some parts of the world, it is blatantly apparent in others. The pattern is quite clear in India’s neighbourhood where it is systematically acquiring real estate for strategic reasons.

*Source*: [How China Is Expanding Global Influence via Debt Trap Diplomacy](https://thewire.in/world/china-debt-trap-diplomacy-south-asia-europe)

In the last 2 decades, after signing a treating with another world power - Russia - the Chinese have also started using their military aggressively against other countries. See this answer here for more details on how [China has been increasingly willing to engage in low-intensity military conflicts in territorial disputes](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/77106/45056) in many parts of Asia.

The increasing use of its army by China mirrors the imperialistic ambitions shown by the old superpowers.

Comment: And here I was thinking that the hallmark of European colonialism was invading countries and subjugating their governments.

Comment: Speaking from an economic perspective, the main reason for colonialism was to (1) find labour, (2) raw material  and (3) to create a market for their goods. Imperialism resulted in one the largest drain wealth from the colonies to the imperialists because of the imbalanced trade they deliberately created.

Comment: From an economic perspective, yeah. But I don't think European powers colonized for economic reasons. They were also spreading religion, civilization, etc.

Comment: Money and expansionism to gain more power were the major goals of the imperialists. Everything else was secondary.

Comment: @Allure Much colonisation was indeed purely economic. Both the East India Company and the Hudson's Bay Company were started by _merchants and traders,_ not governments, though they went on to engage in extensive colonisation activities, and even sometimes war.

Comment: @cjs One could add the Dutch [VOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_East_India_Company) to that list.

Answer (score 5):

Nah, doesn't make much sense.

Take the US.  Depending on the timeline you can perceive a quite peaceful nation.  **Or not.**

From 1800 to 1917 you see a largely isolationist country.  Yes, yes, there is the annexation of Texas, from Mexico, but I'll see you a Tibet.  A little blip too:  Spanish-American war.  Blink, you've missed it.

But you also see a fair bit of meddling in South America, the [banana wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana_Wars).

Still, overall, aside from pestering its Latin American neighbors not all that busy until 1950 - a war started by NK, Russia and China.  Before you object that I am misreading those periods, look at the US military budgets and number of men under arms.  They are low, outside of both world wars (and the Civil War).

From there, yes, you see the America people are used to see swinging big sticks.  But depending on what exact time period you were looking at before, you might expect an entirely different outcome.

OK, now on to China:

- 1949 invasion of Tibet
- 1950 invasion during Korean war
- 1962 invasion in India War
- 1969 near-war with USSR
- 1979 invades Vietnam

From there on?  Peaceful.  So far.  But the military budgets are not low.

You could say that from Mao's death on, China concentrated on building its economy.  You can either read that as China reverted to more peaceful ways.  Or it recognized it couldn't have strong military capabilities without growth.

Looking at the Spratleys and the [Nine Dash Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-dash_line) is also a cause for concern.  In fact, China has, IIRC, territorial disputes with about half of its neighbors (Russia, Pakistan, NK, Myanmar are exceptions.  Lovely friends).  And so is the totalitarian nature of the CCP, if you subscribe to the somewhat questionable theory that democracies do not declare war on each other.  [sfxedit's answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/77125/21531) makes a good point that, as far as resource-seeking diplomacy goes, China may be a lot more like the old boss than it likes to claim.

**China's future behavior, *at the superpower/world stage level*, is *not* preordained from its recent past however.**  It depends mostly on how it and the US decide to manage their growing parity.  To take a swipe also at Asimov: *personalities matter*:  minus Xi and Trump things might have looked very different. So it hard to gauge future trends - looking at the past is unlikely to teach one much:

- a land power with dangerous neighbors is different than an isolated country (the US and modern China are both safe from local threats).
- European nations in the 19th and early 20th century had a strong drive to conflict built in due to their colonial subjugation practices:  they were competing against each other to steal land from others.
- past 1800 (Napoleon and Clausewitz's Total War), Europe is a concentrated powder keg of distrust and militarism until 1945.
- From 1950-1989, NATO and the Warsaw Pact had no choice but to compete globally for supremacy, as they had diametrically opposed ideologies.
- The USSR is also a bit odd, as it was invaded by Western powers in 1919, to punish it for bailing out of WW1.  You don't have to a fan of Communism - I am not - to see that that might influence its world view and behavior.

These are all particular circumstances, unlikely to reappear as such to influence Chinese behavior.

What is also missing from looking at the past is the unique recent circumstances of China:  long *the* dominant regional/world power, then humiliated and mistreated by outside powers, with a helping of massive warlord anarchy in the early 20th century.  Nothing in the above examples matches that.

The one more useful thing to look at, and it is not reassuring, is how often two powers that start out with a power disparity and not on entirely friendly terms [end up in a hot war](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31125556-destined-for-war) as the disparity narrows.

How the US/West and China manage that is still in the future and retro-reading tea leaves doesn't help.

Comment: *Take the US. Depending on the timeline you can perceive a quite peaceful nation* Really? I am under the impression that the US has been at war roughly 90% of the time. https://medium.com/traveling-through-history/only-15-years-of-peace-in-the-history-of-the-united-states-of-america-c479193df79f

Comment: China invaded Vietnam?

Comment: @RedSonja yes, although Italian Philosophers 4 Monica appears to have gotten the year wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Vietnamese_War

Comment: Also, *Peaceful. So far. But the military budgets are not low* Last I saw, the US military budget is roughly 3x that of China's. Shouldn't be surprising, considering the US is at war so often. https://www.visualcapitalist.com/u-s-military-spending-vs-other-top-countries/

Comment: @Allure Love how you seized on a link that touts the - shameful - treatment of native Americans as a harbinger of things to come.  Somehow, that doesn't seem all that relevant to superpower considerations.  Unless of course, you see it as a moral failing that bodes ill on the international scene.  In that case, odd that you overlooked the Uyghurs, Tiananmen and 20M? deaths of the Great Leap Forward.  Nice too how supporting the Afghans after the USSR's 1980  invasion counts  as an US war, per your link.  My point was also not that the US was nice as that you needed to pick your period w care.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica *Unless of course, you see it as a moral failing that bodes ill on the international scene* No, I see it as the US is not a peaceful nation. Uyghurs, Tiananmen, 20 million deaths during the Great Leap Forward are not due to wars. As for the link, I just remembered the statistic, put it into Google, and picked one of the results. If you like, I can always give you the terms to Google for and you can pick your favorite source: "how many years has the us been at peace".

Comment: *Nice too how supporting the Afghans after the USSR's 1980 invasion counts as an US war, per your link* If you prefer, you can do your own year-by-year calculation for how many years the US has been at war. I'd be curious if you can get it under 50%, and if not, how you justify the claim "Depending on the timeline you can perceive a quite peaceful nation".

Comment: OK, 1865 - 1950.  US is dragged into 2 world wars the population mostly wants to sit out.  Before both it has a skeleton military.  After both it demobilizes.  What it does to American natives in between - your supporting link, not mine - is just as relevant to *international* relations as what China does to Uyghurs and Tibetans.  i.e. not very much, that's my point.  I didn't say the US was peaceful - have you read the end of my 2nd paragraph which only has 3 short sentences in it???  Only that it might *seem* so at times makes the OP's exercise somewhat futile.

Comment: Ok, if you dislike the link I'll replace it with this one: https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+many+years+has+the+us+been+at+peace. What it does to American natives is not relevant, because your answer has nothing to do with American natives. Your answer asserts "Depending on the timeline you can perceive a quite peaceful nation", and I contend there is no timeline where you can perceive quite a peaceful nation, because the country has been at war far more often than it has been at peace.

Comment: *1865 - 1950* Did you look at the list of wars? This is the period of the Phillippine-American war, various Indian wars, Spanish-American war, Banana Wars, numerous border skirmishes with Mexico, not counting the two World Wars. So yeah, you'll have to explain why you think the US was a peaceful nation during this period.

Comment: Somehow your key argument that the US was mostly peaceful whereas China is not does not follow from the data you cited yourself. First there is a list of US wars, which are all counted as minor and then there is a list of Chinese wars which are all counted as major although it even includes an almost but not actual war. One can see from your lists that both countries were involved in quite a few wars in time periods considered.

Comment: @Allure *not counting the two World Wars* You're kidding, right?  The US should have been a peaceful country and stayed home for those???  Ask China about that...  Why don't you spend more of your plentiful energy on your own answer?  Done on my end.  Bye.

Comment: "punish it for bailing out of WW1" IIRC it was more like straightforward attempt at regime change, or at least break-up, by supporting the Whites.